# Topology query: If the graph of $f$ is connected and locally compact, then $f$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology

This question is 19.35 from "Elementary Topology Problem Textbook" by Viro et all.

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be such that $\Gamma_f := \{(x, f(x)) : x \in \mathbb R \} \subset \mathbb R^2$ is connected and locally compact. Show that $f$ is continuous.

I tried to follow a similar approach to [If $Gf$ is connected and locally-connected then $f$ is continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044406/if-gf-is-connected-and-locally-connected-then-f-is-continuous), but I don't see how to use local compactness with this approach. Any hints to a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: It should be something like this, I haven't worked out the details, so i dont know if this is actuallly right... Since $\Gamma$ is locally connected, every point $(x,f) \in \Gamma$ has an open neighbourhood $U$ interior to $\Gamma$. Also by connectedness, $U$ is not the union of disjoint open sets.  DOT DOT DOT

Comment: If you show more of an attempt I can help you