# Elementary topology: what is wrong with my proof that a function with connected and locally compact graph is continuous? I didn't need connectivity

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification, compactness, connectedness

So a new user posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4419394/815585) question, with the problem:

> Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ have a connected and locally compact graph $\Gamma_f:=\{(x,f(x)):x\in\Bbb R\}\subset\Bbb R^2$. Show that $f$ is a continuous map.

I started writing an answer for this post, and was about to hit "send" when I realised my answer never once used the connectivity of the graph:

> We want to show that if $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subseteq\Bbb R$ is a sequence which converges to $x\in\Bbb R$ then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. We know that $(x,f(x))$ has a compact neighbourhood $K\subset\Gamma_f$.
>
> Denote the projection maps by $\pi_{1,2}(x,y)=x,y$; since $K$ is compact, $K_1:=\pi_1(K)$ and $K_2:=\pi_2(K)$ are compact since the projection maps are continuous, and they are both neighbourhoods of $x,f(x)$ respectively since the projections maps are open.
>
> Infinitely many of the $(x_n)$ shall lie in $K_1$, so without loss of generality suppose all the $x_n\in K_1$. The sequence $(x_n,f(x_n))\subset K$ and must admit a convergent subsequence, by compactness, hence $(x_{n_k},f(x_{n_k}))$ converges to some $(y,f(y)$ for a subsequence. However, $x_{n_k}\to x$ so we must have $y=x$ and therefore $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x)$. Then all subsequences of $(x_n,f(x_n))$ admit a subsequence convergent to $(x,f(x))$ so we must have $(x_n,f(x_n))\to(x,f(x))$ in $\Gamma_f$ - in particular we must have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

What's the (probably quite basic) oversight that I'm making here? I can't see the problem... all connectivity means to me here is that $K$ cannot be open, but this seems a useless observation. I can certainly visualise functions which are discontinuous as their graphs are disconnected, but cannot make the link with that and my "proof".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming that $K_1$ is a neighborhood of $x$, and this isn't necessarily true. Suppose, for instance, that$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1x&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}$$Its graph is locally compact. And $K=\{(0,0)\}$ is a compact neighborhood of $(0,0)$ in $\Gamma_f$. But $\pi_1(K)=\{0\}$, which is not a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: So I need to show something like: "Suppose $K_1$ is not a neighbourhood of $x$. Then it is compact and hollow ... which somehow implies $K$ is also open in $\Gamma_f$, which means $K$ is clopen, contradicting connectivity"?

Comment: Right now, I don't see how to prove the statement. All I did was to tell you where is the error in your argument, which is what you have asked.

Comment: That is true. Thank you for pointing out the error

Comment: There is another error. Even if $K_1$ is a nbhd of $x$,  the clause "hence, $((x_{n_k}, f(x_{n_k}))_k\to (y,f(y))$for some $y (=x)$" is not valid; it is valid that it converges to $(x,f(z))$ for some $z.$ Assuming $f(z)=f(x)$is not logical.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet but convergence in the graph means that $(x,f(z))$ must be a point of the form $(y,f(y))$ so it follows that $z=x$, no? The compact neighbourhood ensures the limit is inside the graph

Answer (score 1):

An amended (hopefully correct) proof. I believe that once $K_1$ is established to be a neighbourhood of $x$, the rest of my argument follows and is correct. We need connectivity, inspired by Jose's example and by a mental image of e.g. the floor function to conclude $K_1$ is a neighbourhood.

Let $R(p,r)$ denote an open rectangle - $\{(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2:p_x-r\lt a\lt p_x+r\wedge p_y-r\lt b\lt p_y+r\}$, and let $\pi:(x,y)\mapsto x$ be the first projection.

Let $K\ni(x,f(x))$ be the compact neighbourhood as guaranteed by local compactness. As it is a neighbourhood, there is some $r\gt 0$ so that $\Gamma_f\cap R((x,f(x)),r)=: U\subseteq K$.

So let $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\downarrow x$ be any sequence in $\Bbb R$. If infinitely many of the $x_n$ lie in $\pi(U)$, we check the case for $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\uparrow x$ - if infinitely many of the $x_n$ still lie in $\pi(U)$, the proof as above concludes the result as $(x_n,f(x_n))\to (x,f(x))$ within the compact neighbourhood $K$.

In either case, the counterexample is when (without loss of generality) an $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\downarrow x$ but only finitely many lie in the compact neighbourhood $\pi(\overline{U})$. Were $\pi(U)$ open on the right at $x$, this would be impossible - hence this means that there is an $r'\gt0$ so that $x\lt y\le x+r'\implies|f(y)-f(x)|\ge r'$. Then let: $$V_1:=\bigcup_{y\le x}R((y,f(y)),r'/2),\,V_2:=\{(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2:a\gt x\}\cap\bigcup_{y\gt x}R((y,f(y)),3r'/2)$$We have $V_1\cap V_2=\emptyset$, and both are open covers of $\Gamma_f$, which contradicts connectivity. Hence it cannot be the case that a $\Gamma_f$-open neighbourhood of $(x,f(x))$ will fail to have $\Bbb R$-open projection, (as the case where it is not open at the left is treated the same) so if $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\to x$, we can find a compact $\Gamma_f$-neighbourhood $K$ of $(x,f(x))$ with infinitely many of the $(x_n,f(x_n))_{n\in\Bbb N}\in K$ and compactness$\implies$sequential compactness concludes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Incorrect example.

Sorry, not enough rep to comment.

I wanted to ask how this relates to $(x_n, f(x_n)) \to (x, f(x))$. (Sequential) compactness would only guarantee a convergent **subsequence**.

If we take
$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin\frac1x&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}$

and let $x_n = 1/(\frac{n\pi}2) = \frac2{n\pi} $, then infinitely many of the $x_i$ lie in any compact (with nonempty interior) nbhd of $0$, and your method gives a convergent subsequence, but doesn't guarantee that the complete sequence converges.

In this case, $V_{1,2}$ are not disjoint, because the nbhd near $0$ would meet the nbhd of $x_i$ for $i$ a large enough even number. Hence, that method fails.

Or so I think.

Comment: I am aware only a subsequence would be guaranteed. However, if *all subsequences admit a subsequence convergent to the same limit* then the original sequence converges to that limit, which I showed

Comment: And for large $i$, $f(x_i)$ is very large, well outside of the compact graph-neighbourhood $K=\{(0,0)\}$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I made a mistake; the function was supposed to be the topologist's sine curve. Although now that I think of it, it seems it is not locally compact at $0$.

Comment: I'm still struggling to see why $(x_n) \subset \pi_1(K) => (x_n, f(x_n)) \subset K$. It might be possible that infinitely many points lie inside K and infinitely many outside it.

Comment: Because by definition, $x_n$ is in a projection of $\Gamma_f$ only if $(x_n,f(x_n))$ is in the original set (because all elements of the graph are of the form $(x,f(x))$ @methnoob

Comment: And $\pi_1(K)$ contains an open neighbourhood of $x$ if and only if the sequence $x_n$ is “eventually in” (read: infinitely and consistently in after some large $N$) $\pi_1(K)$. I showed in my question that that if this is true then the sequence converges, and I showed in my answer that if this does not hold then we can disconnect the graph

Comment: Yes, you're right. I finally get it now, thank you for your help!

Comment: @methnoob You're welcome. Thank you for noting the exercise book too - this will be very useful to me in the future, and it was instructive for me to give the exercise an attempt (it did take me too long... :) )